# Cross-country e-gift cards

Tags: united-states, canada, online-payment, gift-card

I've been looking for ways to get my friend who lives in the USA an electronic gift card for the holidays *(non-close loop so the card can be used at any store that accepts Visa or MasterCard)*.

I live in Canada and all my payment methods have a Canadian address tied to them so whenever I check out, I can't use any of my payment methods when buying from something like [Vanilla Gift](https://www.vanillagift.com/catalog?type=email) - it won't let me enter a Canadian address for my billing information. I also tried looking at [Visa (Canada)](https://www.visa.ca/en_CA/pay-with-visa/cards/gift-cards.html) so that my billing information would get accepted but while reading, it seems like the gift card can only be used in Canada which doesn't really work for my friend.

What are my options here? Is it even possible for someone from Canada to buy a US Visa gift card in the US?

---

I also tried looking at transferring money through Apple Pay where my friend would simply get an Apple Wallet credit but that seems to be only open to US residents.

Comment: My gut says you can't do that since it would be a great avenue for international illicit money funnels circumventing transfer tracing and reporting requirements. How far from the border do you live? Maybe just drive through the border to the nearest convenience store and buy it there?

Comment: @littleadv I don't really want a physical card, just an e-gift card so it can get delivered instantly.

Comment: @littleadv Do you know if it's possible to do the Apple Pay option though?

Comment: I have no idea, never used Apple Pay

Comment: Suppose you buy from Amazon.com? I know they sell gift cards and I know they accept Canadian credit cards. Might have to be an Amazon card instead of a Visa card.